# No Ajax response post value

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Here I have ajax returning value from database based on selectbox value. My script working but when I tried to look for an array solution, post value not responding in ajax. Why I didn't get the value? Any help will appreciate.

**autocomplete-ajax.php**

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['pr_code'])) {
        $pr_code= $_POST['pr_code'];

        $sql = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM purchase_request WHERE pr='$pr_code'");
        while($row = $sql->fetch_assoc())
        {
            $approved= $row['approved'];
            $requested = $row['requested'];
        }
        echo json_encode(array("approved" => $approved, "requested" => $requested));
    }
?>
```

**Index.php**

```
<?php
    $combo = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM purchase_request GROUP BY pr ORDER BY id");
    $option = '';
    while($row = $combo->fetch_assoc())
    {
        $option .= '<option value = "'.$row['pr'].'">'.$row['pr'].'</option>';
    }
?>
<select id="tag"><option value="">wala</option><?php echo $option; ?></select>
<input name="requested" id="requested" type="text">
<input name="approved" id="approved" type="text">

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
     $('select[id="tag"]').change(function() 
     {
         var pr_code = $("#tag").val();

         $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "autocomplete-ajax.php",
             data :"pr_code="+pr_code,
             dataType:'text',
             type:'POST',
             success:function(data){
                 var approved=data.approved;
                 var requested=data.requested;
                 alert(approved);
                 $('#approved').val()=approved;
                 $('#requested').val()=requested;
            }
       });
       return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to [SQl-Injections](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php). Watch out!!

Comment: First, change `dataType:'text',` to `dataType:'json'`, since you're returning a json array

Comment: Use console.log instead of alert and use chrome's or firefoxes debugging tools. However, I think you would have to at least parse the data you receive on the javscript-site `data = JSON.parse(data);`

Comment: @asprin I got the value in alert, but it's not send to my input fields. Why is that?

Comment: `$('#approved').val(approved);` and  `$('#requested').val(requested);`